# Firestore read request is very slow when creating a document reference

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, latency

So, I'm having some latency issues between my backend and Google Cloud Firestore. I have this read function which is taking approximately 1.2 seconds to run:

```js
async read(req: Request, res: Response) {
    console.time("start");
    const userUid = req.uid;
    const { placeUid, roomUid } = req.params;

    const userRef = firestore.collection("Users").doc(userUid);
    const placeRef = userRef.collection("Places").doc(placeUid);
    const roomRef = placeRef.collection("Rooms").doc(roomUid);
    console.timeEnd("start");
    
    console.time("roomRequest");
    let room;
    try {
      room = await roomRef.withConverter(roomConverter).get();
    } catch (error) {
      return res.status(500).json(error);
    }
    console.timeEnd("roomRequest");

    if (!room.exists) return res.status(400).json(errors.roomDoesNotExist);

    console.time("dataRequest");
    const roomData = room.data();
    let devices: Array<Object>;
    if (roomData) {
      devices = await Promise.all(
        roomData?.devices.map(async (device): Promise<Object> => {
          const deviceData = (await device.get()).data();
          return { id: device.id, name: deviceData?.name };
        })
      );
    } else devices = [];
    console.timeEnd("dataRequest");

    return res.json({ uid: room.id, name: roomData?.name, devices });
  }
```

I've put some `console.time` logs to log the performance, and these are the results:

```
start: 0.739ms
roomRequest: 415.584ms
dataRequest: 76.982ms
```

I found it pretty strange that the section that takes the longest to run is the `start` section.

I import firestore from this file:

```js
import admin from "firebase-admin";
import { resolve } from "path";

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(resolve(__dirname, "key.json")),
});

const firestore = admin.firestore();

export { firestore };
```

It isn't a database region problem because I live very close to the GCP region. It takes 1.2, 1.5 seconds for every request I make, not only the first one. What should I do to avoid this issue?

Comment: hey there! Could you please tell me if you solved this issue?

Comment: Hello Samuel! I'm sorry, but I didn't.